# Formal HDL verification with PSL

Tags: vhdl, formal-verification

I am trying to learn Formal Verification for VHDL design (using Property Specification Language). My module has an active-low reset input. I would like to drive tool to set the reset input to '0' for 1 clk and to '1' for all others.

I've tried the following code:

```
vunit i_test(test(rtl))
{
  -- set all declarations to run on clk
  default clock is rising_edge(clk_i);

  f_reset_0 : assume (rst_n_i = '0');
  f_reset_1 : assume always (next rst_n_i); -- tried also without this line
  f_post_reset_out_en  : assert always {rst_n_i = '0'} |=> {out_en_o = '0'};

  f_sum : assert always {rst_n_i = '1'} |=> {not(out_o = x"AE")};
}
```

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the PSL `restrict` directive to model your Reset behavior. It is used to say the tool that every "run" has to match the given SERE. Or, with other words, every exploration has to fulfill the behavior given using the `restrict` directive.

From the book **A Practical Introduction to PSL**:

```
restrict: This directive restricts a verification tool to
constrain the verification so that it matches a SERE. For
instance, restrict {a ; b ;
c[*]} instructs the tool to consider only traces every prefix of which
matches {a ; b ; c[*]}.
```

This should do what you want:

```vhdl
INITIAL_RESET : restrict {not rst_n_i[*1]; rst_n_i[+]}[*1];
```

`not rst_n_i[*1]` rst_n_i = '0' in the first cycle

`;` Skip to the next cycle

`rst_n_i[+]` rst_n_i = '0' in the next cycle, repeating a non-zero number of repetitions

`{not rst_n_i[*1]; rst_n_i[+]}[*1]` Matches for exactly one occurrence of the whole sequence.

So the only valid sequence is exactly that one you want:

```
clk_i:    -_-_-_-_....-_-_
rst_n_i:  -_______....____
```

The assume directive has a subtle different meaning. It's useful to constrain the behavior of inputs, so that all properties only have to hold under these constraints.

From the book **A Practical Introduction to PSL**:

> assume: This directive instructs a verification tool to constrain the verifi-
> cation so that a property holds. In other words, it instructs the verification
> tool that any asserted properties need not hold on traces that do not obey
> the assumptions.